# Automatically send certain filetypes to preset location

Tags: automation, file-management, sorting, save-as, offline-files

So the workflow I'm going for is saving the active webpage as .MHTML using a keystroke and make it go into a pre-set save location, so there's no interruption to browsing. I can easily get the .MHTML with a keystroke with an extension like "Save Page Offline" for chrome, but how would you get the .MHTML files to go to a preset location? By default they all go in my Downloads folder, but how would you make them go to \Downloads\OfflineWeb?

I've tried a number of software solutions to move files on a schedule. That wouldn't be so bad if they offered a more frequent refresh rate (most of them do it once a day at most).

How do you send certain file types to a specific location, or how do you automatically move certain filetypes as soon as they're found in a folder?

Ideally the solution would not depend on using a specific browser.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/psa-file-organizer-move-specific-file-type-another-folder

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: https://dotnet-helpers.com/powershell/how-to-move-files-from-one-location-to-another-location-using-powershell/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439821/how-to-only-move-specific-file-types-in-powershell

Comment: Thanks but none of those allow the automatic moving of files. They are all manual.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870201/how-to-loop-my-powershell-script or Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AutoHotKey can handle this pretty well. I was going to try and automate running a powershell script with Task Scheduler but it started to get overly complicated for a trivially simple task and I gave up. Instead I wrote this super simple little AHK script that does this flawlessly:

```
#NoEnv 

Loop{
FileMove, C:\Users\AccountName\Downloads\*.mhtml, C:\Users\AccountName\Downloads\OfflineWeb\
Sleep 60000
}
```

Added to startup with AHK AddToStartup and it automatically moves .mhtml every 60 seconds.